# proof reading and a little question and refine english about college-algebra

Tags: polynomials

## Welcome to edit my post to revise any mistakes, both English and Math, thanks.

---

### Theorem 12

polyIC=integer polynomial

polyRC=rational polynomial

Suppose $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\text{...}+a_0$ is a polyIC, and $\frac{r}{s}$ is a rational root, where $(r,s)=1$.

Then we must have $s\left|a_n\right.,r\left|a_0\right.$. Specially, If the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ satisfies $a_n=1$,

then the rational roots of $f(x)$ are all integer roots, and they are factors of $a_0$.

---

### Proof$\unicode{ff1a}$

Because $\frac{r}{s}$ is an rational root of $f(x)$. On rational number field $\left.\left(x-\frac{r}{s}\right)\right|f(x)$.

Thus $[\text{Mark1}]$ $(\text{sx}-r)|f(x)$.  For $(r,s)=1$, $s x-r$ is an primitive polynomial.

Conclude from above, $f(x)=(s x-r)\left(b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\text{...}+b_0\right)$,where $b_{n-1},\text{...},b_0$ are all integers.

Compare the coefficients of two sides, that is $a_n=s b_{n-1},a_0=-r b_0$.

Hence $s\left|a_n\right.,r\left|a_0\right.$.

---

### one little question

Does $[\text{Mark1}]$ so obvious?

$\left.\left(x-\frac{r}{s}\right)\right|f(x)$ $\Longrightarrow $ $s|f(x)$

of course, this is obvious in this example: f below, has one rational root-4/5$\unicode{ff0c}$so 5(x-4/5)$|$f(x)

$\pmb{f=25\left(x-\frac{4}{5}\right)(x-2)\left(x+\frac{4}{5}\right)\text{//}\text{Expand}}$

$32-16 x-50 x^2+25 x^3$

$\pmb{\text{Solve}[f==0,x]}$

$\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{4}{5}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{4}{5}\right\},\{x\to 2\}\right\}$

$\pmb{\text{Factor}[f]}$

$(-2+x) (-4+5 x) (4+5 x)$

$\pmb{5(x-4/5)\text{//}\text{Expand}}$

$-4+5 x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide a polynomial $f$ with rational coefficients by $x-t$ with $t$ rational, you get a quotient polynomial with rational coefficients and a rational number as remainder; $$f(x)=(x-t)q(x)+r$$ Now let $x=t$, and you get $f(t)=r$. So if $f(t)=0$, then $r=0$, so $f(x)=(x-t)q(x)$, so $x-t$ divides $f(x)$.

Comment: oh, my mistake. question in [mark1] is about the step $(x-r/s)$ divides $f(x)$ so $(sx-r)$ divides $f(x)$

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-(r/s))q(x)$, then $f(x)=(sx-r)p(x)$, where $p(x)=(1/s)q(x)$.

Comment: ok, thanks, so in [mark1] it's enough to not show this,right?
another question: Which is right? terminology integer[a noun] polynomial or integeral polynomial? rational[a adj?] polynomial

Comment: The trouble with both "integer polynomial" and "integral polynomial" is that it's not clear whether you're referring to the coefficients or the values, e.g., $(x^2-x)/2$ doesn't have integer coefficients but always gives integer values for an integer $x$. To avoid ambiguity, I'd write, "polynomial with integer coefficients". But there's nothing wrong with using "integer polynomial" or "integral polynomial" if you first tell people exactly what you mean by the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

By the Factor Theorem $\, f(r/s)=0\,\Rightarrow\, f = (x-r/s)\, g= (sx-r)\, h,\ h = g/s.\ $ Therefore $\,(r,s)=1\,\Rightarrow\,sx\!-\!r\,$ primitive, thus $\,(sx\!-\!r)h = f\in \Bbb Z[x]\Rightarrow h\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ by Gauss's Lemma.

Therefore, with $\,\ell f := $ lead coef of $\,f,\,$ we have $\, s\mid \ell f = \ell((sx\!-\!r)h) = s\, \ell (h),\,$ and $\,r\mid f(0) = -r\,h(0),\ $ since $\ \ell(h),h(0)\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by $\,h\in\Bbb Z[x].$

Comment: thanks, I should learn your way in writing math in an consise way, such like `h belongs to Z[x]` .Though I'm take the purpose of improving math-writing-english, welcome to edit my mistakes. :)